# Text-align: center not working on jQuery ul drop down menu

Tags: html, css, text-align

A jQuery drop down menu on a site I'm created is not centering text in an unordered list (ul) properly, and I cannot see why, seeing as on a [site I made](http://studioforte.ca) with a similar layout this works perfectly. Seen other stack overflow answers but none of them answer my situation. 
HTML:

```
 <div class="menu">
        <ul class="menulinks">
            <a href="#"><li> Music </li> </a>
            <a href="#"><li> Trending </li> </a>
            <a href="#"><li> Interesting </li> </a>
            <a href="#"> <li>Funny </li> </a>
            <a href="#"> <li> Events </li> </a>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
.menulinks {
/* text-align: center; */
width: 100vw;
margin-left: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}
.menulinks li {
text-align: center;
list-style-type: none;
padding-top: 1vh;
padding-bottom: 1vh;
}
```

All my code is on http://jsfiddle.net/3840yv1y/4/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logo is causing the problem:

```css
.logo {
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-top: 2vh;
    padding-bottom: 2vh;
    float: left;
}
```

Since it is styled as `float: left;` and appears to the left of the items at the top of the menu, the first few items in the drop-down list are being squeezed over to the right.

Absolute positioning will fix this for you:

```css
.logo {
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-top: 2vh;
    padding-bottom: 2vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

[(Updated JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/3840yv1y/3/)

Comment: That did help the first three (thank you!) but the last 2 are still not centred

Comment: Oh it could be the same problem just with the hamburger icon on the right (float: right). I'll check it out

Comment: Yes - changed float:right to position:absolute here as well and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your list markup is invalid. It's always ul > li > a

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

Comment: I am aware of that, I do that so not only the text will be a link but the entire <li> (which takes up the entire screen). If I encounter any errors however I'll be sure to take care of it, however so far it seems to work fine.

Comment: No but seriously, you can't just place an unordered list in your html, and then be like "oh i don't need list items. i'll just use anchors." If using list items inside your list gives you errors or unwanted behaviour, you are writing bad code.

Comment: Hmm. As in, let's say the <li>'s were divs. I would want the a link to target the entire div, not just the text inside the div as it would be if the <a>'s were inside the <li>s. Does that make sense?

Comment: In that case you would still use ul > li > a. Only this time do a display:block on the anchor to make it fill the entire height and width of the list item.

Comment: Thank you that was logical and useful.